# Customizing the table of contents with two colors in Latex

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

In my document I want to use two colours in table of contents to differentiate the work between two authors. For instance,

- The chapters, sections and subsections coloured in blue are written by author X and in red colour are written by author Y.

In some chapters, sections and subsections are written by both of the authors. For example in chapter A(Blue),

- Section 1(Blue) is written by X.
- Subsection 1.1(Red) and section 2(Red) are written by Y.

Finally, these colours must be only changed in table of contents but not in the content of the document.

How can I customize like that? Would anybody be able to help with something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) you have control over the formatting of every entry type within the ToC. For chapters there's `\cftchapfont`, for sections there's `\cftsecfont` and subsections have `\cftsubsecfont`.

Below provide `\authoredby{<name>}` which inserts an entry into the ToC for changing the colour. Additionally, author colours can be defined using `\defineauthorcolor{<name>}{<colour>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,xcolor}

\newcommand{\defineauthorcolor}[2]{%
  \colorlet{author#1}{#2}% Create an author colour
  \expandafter\def\csname authoredby#1\endcsname{% Create author colour settings
    \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\color{author#1}}% Chapter colour
    \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{author#1}}% Section colour
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{author#1}}}% Subsection colour
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\authoredby}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\@nameuse{authoredby#1}}}%
\makeatother

\defineauthorcolor{A}{red}% Author A will be coloured red
\defineauthorcolor{B}{blue}% Author B will be coloured blue

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\authoredby{A}
\chapter{A chapter}
\authoredby{B}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\authoredby{A}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\authoredby{B}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}

\authoredby{A}
\chapter{Last chapter}

\end{document}
```

The `.toc` for the above minimal example looks like this:

```
\@nameuse {authoredbyA}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}A chapter}{3}
\@nameuse {authoredbyB}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A section}{3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}A subsection}{3}
\@nameuse {authoredbyA}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Another section}{3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Another subsection}{3}
\@nameuse {authoredbyB}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Yet another subsection}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Another chapter}{5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}First section}{5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}Second section}{5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}Last section}{5}
\@nameuse {authoredbyA}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Last chapter}{7}
```

Each use of `\authoredby{<name>}` inserts the `\@nameuse{authoredby<name>}` into the ToC to switch the colour accordingly. Note that this solution works for any number of authors (not just limited to two).

This solution should work with the [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls), [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) and [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document classes.